# A question about the proof of Weyl's inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $A,B$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices, then a version of Weyl's inequalities states that

$$\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_n(B)\leq\lambda_k(A+B)\leq \lambda_k(A)+\lambda_1(B) \quad 1\leq k\leq n,$$

where $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$th largest eigenvalue.

Consider the following proof of the rightmost inequality, making use of the min-max characterization of eigenvalues for a Hermitian matrix:

$$\lambda_k(A+B)=­\min_{U\subset F^n,  \text{dim } U=k} \max_{v\in U,v\neq 0} R_{A+B}(v)=­\min_{U\subset F^n,  \text{dim } U=k}\max_{v\in U,v\neq 0} [R_{A}(v)+R_B(v)]$$
$$\leq\min_{U\subset F^n,  \text{dim } U=k} \max_{v\in U,v\neq 0}[ R_{A}(v)+\lambda_1(B)]=\min_{U\subset F^n,  \text{dim } U=k}\max_{v\in U,v\neq 0}  R_{A}(v) +\lambda_1(B)=\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_1(B),$$

where $R_{C}$ denotes the Rayleigh quotient of $C$.

In my notes it is written that the leftmost inequality can be proven similarly using the max-min characterization. However looking at the above proof it seems that replacing $\lambda_1(B)$ with $\lambda_n(B)$ and reversing the inequality sign also gives a proof.

Can we use both the min-max and max-min chracterization of eigenvalues to prove  Weyl's inequalities? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the proof you exhibited has got the dimension of $U$ wrong. E.g. when $k=1$, the first equality in your proof gives
$$
\lambda_1(A+B)=­\min_{U\subset F^n,\,\dim U=1}\ \max_{v\in U,v\neq 0} R_{A+B}(v).
$$
If you write $U=\operatorname{span}(v)$, the RHS above reduces to $\min_{v\ne0}R_{A+B}(v)$, which is actually $\lambda_n(A+B)$, not $\lambda_1(A+B)$.

To correct the proof, the dimension of $U$ should be $n+1-k$ rather than $k$:
\begin{align}
\lambda_k(A+B)
&=­\min_{\dim U=n+1-k}\ \max_{v\in U\setminus0} R_{A+B}(v)\\
&=­\min_{\dim U=n+1-k}\ \max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+R_B(v)\right)\\
&\leq­\min_{\dim U=n+1-k}\ \max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+\lambda_1(B)\right)\tag{1}\\
&=­\left(\min_{\dim U=n+1-k}\ \max_{v\in U\setminus0} R_A(v)\right)+\lambda_1(B)\\
&=\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_1(B).
\end{align}
Now, return to your question. Can we replace $\lambda_1(B)$ by $\lambda_n(B)$ in the first proof (that uses min-max characterisation) and reverse the directions of the inequalities? Yes, but we need to be careful in justifying the inequality analogous to line $(1)$. In line $(1)$, we may argue as follows. For every nonzero subspace $U$, let $v_0\in U\setminus0$ be the maximiser of $R_A(v)+R_B(v)$. Then
\begin{align}
\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+R_B(v)\right)
&=R_A(v_0)+R_B(v_0)\\
&\leq R_A(v_0)+\lambda_1(B)\\
&\leq\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+\lambda_1(B)\right).
\end{align}
Since this is true for every $U$, it is also true for their minimum values over all $U$s of dimensions $n+1-k$. Hence $(1)$ is justified. However, if we simply replace $\lambda_1(B)$ by $\lambda_n(B)$ and reverse the directions of the inequalities in the above argument, we will get
\begin{aligned}
\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+R_B(v)\right)
&=R_A(v_0)+R_B(v_0)\\
&\geq R_A(v_0)+\lambda_n(B)\\
&\color{red}{\geq}\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+\lambda_n(B)\right),
\end{aligned}
which is not correct. To correct the argument, we should pick $v_0$ as the maximiser of $R_A(v)$ over $U\setminus0$ instead. Then
\begin{aligned}
\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+R_B(v)\right)
&\color{red}{\geq} R_A(v_0)+R_B(v_0)\\
&\geq R_A(v_0)+\lambda_n(B)\\
&\color{red}{=}\max_{v\in U\setminus0} \left(R_A(v)+\lambda_n(B)\right),
\end{aligned}
Since this is true for every nonzero subspace $U$, if we minimises both sides in the above over all $(n+1-k)$-dimensional subspaces $U$, we obtain $\lambda_k(A+B)\ge\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_n(B)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I realize I reversed the order of eigenvalues used in the min-max theorem. When you say that the RHS reduce to $\min_{v\ne0}R_{A+B}(v)$, this is because $R_{A+B}(cv)=R_{A+B}(v)$ for any nonzero scalar $c$ so that $­\min_{U\subset F^n,\,\dim U=1}\ \max_{v\in U,v\neq 0} R_{A+B}(v)=­\min_{span(v), v\neq 0} R_{A+B}(v)=\min_{v\neq 0} R_{A+B}(v)$?

Comment: When you write: Since this is true for every $U$, it is also true for their minimum values over all $U$'s, don't we need to repeat an analogous argument here?

Comment: I believe the general fact is this : If $(a_i)_{i\in I},(b_i)_{i\in I}$ are two indexed sets of real numbers having minimums and maximums and such that $a_i\leq b_i$ for all $i\in I$, then $\min_{i\in I} a_i\leq \min_{i\in I} b_i$ and $\max_{i\in I} a_i\leq \max_{i\in I} b_i$. The min case is proven by choosing $i_0$ such that  $\min_{i\in I} b_i=b_{i_0}\geq a_{i_0}\geq \min_{i\in I} a_i$ while the max case is proven by choosing $i_0$  such that $\max_{i\in I} a_i=a_{i_0}\leq b_{i_0}\leq \max_{i\in I} b_i$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Alphie Yes, yes and yes.